# How can I add new methods to Iterator?

Tags: iterator, rust

I want to define a `.unique()` method on iterators that enables me to iterate without duplicates.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

struct UniqueState<'a> {
    seen: HashSet<String>,
    underlying: &'a mut Iterator<Item = String>,
}

trait Unique {
    fn unique(&mut self) -> UniqueState;
}

impl Unique for Iterator<Item = String> {
    fn unique(&mut self) -> UniqueState {
        UniqueState {
            seen: HashSet::new(),
            underlying: self,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for UniqueState<'a> {
    type Item = String;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        while let Some(x) = self.underlying.next() {
            if !self.seen.contains(&x) {
                self.seen.insert(x.clone());
                return Some(x);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

This compiles. However, when I try to use in the same file:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = vec!["a", "b", "a", "cc", "cc", "d"];

    for s in foo.iter().unique() {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `unique` found for type `std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:37:25
   |
37 |     for s in foo.iter().unique() {
   |                         ^^^^^^
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `unique`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Unique`
```

What am I doing wrong? How would I extend this arbitrary hashable types?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your particular case, it's because you have implemented your trait for an iterator of `String`, but your vector is providing an iterator of `&str`. Here's a more generic version:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::Hash;

struct Unique<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    seen: HashSet<I::Item>,
    underlying: I,
}

impl<I> Iterator for Unique<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Hash + Eq + Clone,
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        while let Some(x) = self.underlying.next() {
            if !self.seen.contains(&x) {
                self.seen.insert(x.clone());
                return Some(x);
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

trait UniqueExt: Iterator {
    fn unique(self) -> Unique<Self>
    where
        Self::Item: Hash + Eq + Clone,
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Unique {
            seen: HashSet::new(),
            underlying: self,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> UniqueExt for I {}

fn main() {
    let foo = vec!["a", "b", "a", "cc", "cc", "d"];

    for s in foo.iter().unique() {
        println!("{}", s);
    }
}
```

Broadly, we create a new *extension trait* called `UniqueExt` which has `Iterator` as a supertrait. When `Iterator` is a supertrait, we will have access to the *associated type* `Iterator::Item`.

This trait defines the `unique` method, which is only valid to call when then iterated item can be:

1. Hashed
2. Compared for total equality
3. Cloned

Additionally, it requires that the item implementing `Iterator` have a known size at compile time. This is done so that the iterator can be *consumed* by the `Unique` iterator adapter.

The other important part is the *blanket implementation* of the trait for any type that also implements `Iterator`:

```
impl<I: Iterator> UniqueExt for I {}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm going to throw this up on crates.io, I hope that's OK.

Comment: @WilfredHughes That's fine, but you may wish to contribute it to the [itertools crate](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/index.html), which is a great repository for these types of additions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @Shepmaster.  This example helped resolve several issues for me that I haven't seen in any docs I've read--in fact, this is the *only* answer I can recall having read showing how to create generic extension methods against Iterator.  Both question and answer are much appreciated.