# What is the canonical way to implement is_empty for Iterator?

Tags: rust

I have something that implements `std::iter::Iterator` and I want to know if there are `> 0` elements. What is the standard way to do it? `count() > 0` looks too expensive.

I see two candidates: `any(|_| true)` and `nth(0).is_some()`, but which one should I pick so a future reader can understand on sight what I'm checking here?

Answer (score 27):

I would write `iter.next().is_some()`.

However, you need to be aware that doing this *advances the iterator*.

```
fn main() {
    let scores = [1, 2, 3];
    let mut iter = scores.iter();
    
    println!("{}", iter.next().is_some()); // true
    println!("{}", iter.next().is_some()); // true
    println!("{}", iter.next().is_some()); // true
    println!("{}", iter.next().is_some()); // false
}
```

In many cases I'd use [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html):

```
fn main() {
    let scores = [1, 2, 3];
    let mut iter = scores.iter().peekable();
    
    println!("{}", iter.peek().is_some()); // true
    println!("{}", iter.peek().is_some()); // true
    println!("{}", iter.peek().is_some()); // true
    println!("{}", iter.peek().is_some()); // true
}
```

> so a future reader can understand on sight

I'd [add a method on iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30540766/155423) named `is_empty`.

Comment: Summing up: `let is_empty = scores.iter().peekable().peek().is_none();`.

Comment: @rodrigocfd: If you drop the iterator anyways, you can skip the `peekable` part. Only if you still need it, you should make it peekable and then peek.

Answer (score 13):

The canonical way to implement `is_empty` for `Iterator` is not to do so. An `Iterator` is [lazy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/index.html#laziness), so by definition cannot know if it has any more elements without iterating.

Logically, it might seem as if it should be simple for an Iterator to know whether it has any more elements, but that can only be the case (without iterating) if its size in known. And indeed, [ExactSizeIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html#method.is_empty) implements `is_empty`.

To check whether an `Iterator` is empty, you must attempt to iterate and check if you receive `None`, however (as mentioned by @Shepmaster), you can only do so without advancing the `Iterator` when you have a `Peekable` `Iterator`. You can `peek()` at the next element and check if it `is_none()`:

```
let mut iterator = vec![1,2,3].into_iter().peekable();
println!("is_empty: {}", iterator.peek().is_none());
```

This becomes more obvious when considering that an to implement `Iterator`, one only needs to provide a `next` function that returns either `Some` or `None` to indicate whether further elements exist. We could provide an implementation of `next` that randomly decides whether the next element exists, which makes it clear that we can't know without executing `next` whether our iterator is empty:

```
struct RandomThings {}
impl Iterator for RandomThings {
    type Item = bool;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<bool> {
        let has_next = rand::random::<bool>();
        if has_next {Some(true)} else {None}
    }
}
```

So creating a `Peekable` Iterator and calling `.peek().is_none()` is actually very explicit, and should be easily understood by future readers. If you are only dealing with iterators of known size, then you can constrain your type further to `ExactSizeIterator` and use `is_empty`. If you were to add `is_empty` for an ordinary `Iterator` you would only be hiding the fact that its `next` function must be called to determine whether it is empty.