# Is it possible to split a vector into groups of 10 with iterators?

Tags: vector, iterator, rust

I have `let my_vec = (0..25).collect::<Vec<_>>()` and I would like to split `my_vec` into iterators of groups of 10:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, None, None, None, None, None];
```

Is it possible to do that with iterators in Rust?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no such helper method on the [`Iterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) directly. However, there are two main ways to do it:

1. Use the [**`[T]::chunks()`** method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) (which can be called on a `Vec<T>` directly). However, it has a minor difference: it won't produce `None`, but the last iteration yields a smaller slice. For always-exact slices that omit the final chunk if it's incomplete, see the [**`[T]::chunks_exact()`** method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact).

[Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd039c1922449815618ebfd58de938e4&version=stable):

```
    let my_vec = (0..25).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for chunk in my_vec.chunks(10) {
        println!("{:02?}", chunk);
    }
```

Result:

````
```none
[00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```
````

2. Use the [**`Itertools::chunks()`** method](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks) from [the crate `itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools). This crate extends the `Iterator` trait from the standard library so this `chunks()` method works with all iterators! Note that the usage is slightly more complicated in order to be that general. This has the same behavior as the method described above: in the last iteration, the chunk will be smaller instead of containing `None`s.

[Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=de485e2ea81a861f649fe6fea5fbd89f&version=stable):

```
    extern crate itertools;
    use itertools::Itertools;
    
    for chunk in &(0..25).chunks(10) {
        println!("{:02?}", chunk.collect::<Vec<_>>());
    }
```

Result:

````
```none
[00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```
````

Comment: Thanks! The first solution was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: chunks seems to be a part of std now, so no need in itertools for it

Comment: @gekh `chunks` still doesn't exist on `Iterator`. There is `[T]::chunks` and `Iterator::array_chunks`, which are both neat, but don't do the same as `IterTools::chunks`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I use it like this `some_vec[start..end].chunks(split)`

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve a similar solution as [Lukas Kalbertodt's itertools example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867634/155423) using only the standard library:

```
let my_vec = (0..25).collect::<Vec<_>>();

let mut my_values = my_vec.into_iter().peekable();

while my_values.peek().is_some() {
    let chunk: Vec<_> = my_values.by_ref().take(10).collect();
    println!("{:?}", chunk);
}
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

If you don't actually need the `Vec` of each chunk, you can omit the `collect` call and operate directly on the iterator created by `by_ref`.

See also:

- [What is the canonical way to implement is_empty for Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45761364/155423)
- [Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134874/155423)
- [Why does Iterator::take_while take ownership of the iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31374051/155423)
- [Using the same iterator multiple times in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23969191/155423)

Answer (score 1):

A trick I adapted from Python to get a `groupby()` effect like Python's `itertools` provides is to combine two or more iterators  using `.zip()`, `.skip()` and `.step_by()`. This approach could produce groups of 10, but it would be quite unaesthetic to see in a code base. But if you need small groups, this may be okay.

Rust does have the `itertools` crate which has `.group_by()`, but that's not always available depending on the situation - for instance, submitting a Rust solution to sites like HackerRank.

```rust
fn main()
{
    let a = "Hello, World!";

    println!("{:?}", a.chars().step_by(2).zip(
                         a.chars().skip(1).step_by(2) 
                     ).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Output:

```
[('H', 'e'), ('l', 'l'), ('o', ','), (' ', 'W'), ('o', 'r'), ('l', 'd')]
```

Where `n` is the number of zipped iterators, the value for `.step_by` will be `n` for all iterators, and the value for `.skip()` will depend on the position of the iterator in the chain; the first iterator will skip 0, the next 1, etc.

You can chain any number of iterators this way, but it starts looking a bit complicated and ugly after the third. In that case, maybe consider just collecting the iterator into a `Vec` and using its `.chunks()` method. Or if you can, use the `itertools` crate.

Answer (score 0):

Chunks one vector with or without use rayon.
And then map some function to each part.
In the following example, the sum function was used.

```
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let my_vec: Vec<_> = (0..25).collect();
    let chunk_size = 10;

    let chunks_without_rayon: Vec<_> = my_vec
        .chunks(chunk_size)
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, chunk)| {
            println!("chunk{i}: {chunk:?}");
            chunk.iter().sum::<i32>()
        })
        .collect();

    println!("chunks_without_rayon = {chunks_without_rayon:?}\n");

    let chunks_with_rayon: Vec<_> = my_vec
        .par_chunks(chunk_size)
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, chunk)| {
            println!("chunk{i}: {chunk:?}");
            chunk.iter().sum::<i32>()
        })
        .collect();

    println!("chunks_with_rayon: {chunks_with_rayon:?}")
}
```

The output:

```
chunk0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chunk1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
chunk2: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
chunks_without_rayon = [45, 145, 110]

chunk0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chunk1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
chunk2: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
chunks_with_rayon: [45, 145, 110]
```