# How can I use the question mark operator while iterating over references to Result?

Tags: rust, iterator

I need to chunk my vector `Vec<Result<SomeStruct>>` into pieces, iterate over each piece, do some work, and return an error if `Result<SomeStruct>` contains it.

```
enum SomeStruct {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SomeError {}

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, SomeError>;

fn foo(v: Vec<Result<SomeStruct>>) -> Result<()> {
    for chunk in v.chunks(42) {
        for value in chunk {
            let value = value?;
            //do smth with value
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut values = Vec::new();
    foo(values).unwrap();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b5198ba04f1f32786b15451c849f050)

However, I get the error

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be applied to values that implement `std::ops::Try`
  --> src/main.rs:11:25
   |
11 |             let value = value?;
   |                         ^^^^^^ the `?` operator cannot be applied to type `&std::result::Result<SomeStruct, SomeError>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `&std::result::Result<SomeStruct, SomeError>`
   = note: required by `std::ops::Try::into_result`
```

It seems `?` expects the value itself instead of a shared reference to the value, but I can't dereference a shared reference and don't know how to get this value itself because `chunk` here is `&[Result<SomeStruct>]`, and `value` is `&Result<SomeStruct>`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're doing that requires chunking? You may be able to just use a straight-up `for` loop over `v` instead, pausing every 42 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General case

Your function signature requires that you return an *owned* `SomeError`, but all you have is a reference to one. Unless you have *some* way of converting a `&SomeError` into a `SomeError`, this problem is unsolvable.

The most applicable solution is to change your error to be clonable (or copyable, if appropriate) and then convert your `&Result<T, E>` into a `Result<&T, E>` via [`Result::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_ref) and [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err):

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct SomeError {}
```

```
for value in chunk {
    let value = value.as_ref().map_err(Clone::clone)?;
    // do something with `value`
}
```

Also possible, but far less common, would be to return a *reference* to the error. This requires that the error lives longer than the call to the function:

```
type Result<T, E = SomeError> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn foo(v: &[Result<SomeStruct>]) -> Result<(), &SomeError> {
    for chunk in v.chunks(42) {
        for value in chunk {
            let value = value.as_ref()?;
            // do something with `value`
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let values = Vec::new();
    foo(&values).unwrap();
}
```

See also:

- [How do I borrow a reference to what is inside an Option<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22282117/155423)
- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

## Specific case

Since you take ownership of the `Vec` and don't make use of the fact that the inner iterator is a slice, you don't need to have a `&Result` to start with. Instead, convert the `Vec` into an iterator and `take` chunk-length pieces of it:

```
fn foo(v: Vec<Result<SomeStruct>>) -> Result<()> {
    let mut v = v.into_iter().peekable();

    while v.peek().is_some() {
        for value in v.by_ref().take(42) {
            let _value = value?;
            // do something with `value`
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

You can also use [`Itertools::chunks`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks):

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.1

fn foo(v: Vec<Result<SomeStruct>>) -> Result<()> {
    for chunk in &v.into_iter().chunks(42) {
        for value in chunk {
            let value = value?;
            // do something with `value`
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

See also:

- [What is the canonical way to implement is_empty for Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45761364/155423)
- [Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134874/155423)
- [Is it possible to split a vector into groups of 10 with iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46867355/155423)

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding the Error

Here is the signature of `Vec::chunks`:

```rust
pub fn chunks(&self, chunk_size: usize) -> Chunks<T>
```

Notice `&self`, because the `Chunks<T>` returned has an iterator of type `Item = &'a [T]`.  When you iterate over this slice (each chunks is a slice) you get a reference to a `T`.  Hence the error the compiler gives:

```
the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `&std::result::Result<SomeStruct, SomeError>`
```

Basically this is saying `Try` is not implemented for `&Result<SomeStruct>`.

### Solution

I don't think it is not possible to take ownership of a reference of a slice (without copying).

#### Copy to a `Vec`:

You can use `to_vec` on the slice (chunk) provided that `SomeStruct` & `SomeError` implement `Clone`.

#### Use `SomeStruct` as a reference:

Since your code returns `Ok(())`, you might be able to use a `&SomeStruct` in `//do smth with value`.  In fact this is a common, and very useful pattern in Rust:

```rust
fn do_something_with_value(v: &SomeStruct) {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

Comment: You can also write `let value = value.as_ref().map_err(SomeError::clone)?` (adding a `derive(Clone)` for the `SomeError`) and clone only in the case of error.

Comment: @Shepmaster you are right, if `to_vec` is used `SomeError` also needs to be cloneable.  Thanks.  I updated the answer.