# Is there a way to deplete an iterator after calling Iterator::take?

Tags: iterator, rust

I have an iterator that I would like to analyze using a sliding window of size `w`. I try to move the first `w` items from the iterator into a data structure and would like iterate through the remaining items. However, when I use `numbers.take(w)` I lose ownership of the iterator and cannot consume the remaining items:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub fn analysis<I>(numbers: I, w: usize)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = u64>,
{
    let mut window = VecDeque::with_capacity(w);
    for number in numbers.take(w) {
        window.push_back(number);
    }

    for (i, number) in numbers.enumerate() {
        // do some analysis
    }
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `numbers`
  --> src/main.rs:12:24
   |
8  |     for number in numbers.take(w) {
   |                   ------- value moved here
...
12 |     for (i, number) in numbers.enumerate() {
   |                        ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `numbers` has type `I`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I found a workaround using the `tee` function from the `itertools` crate:

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;
use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub fn analysis<I>(numbers: I, w: usize)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = u64>,
{
    let mut window = VecDeque::with_capacity(w);
    let (first_numbers, numbers) = numbers.tee();

    for number in first_numbers.take(w) {
        window.push_back(number);
    }

    for number in numbers.skip(w) {
        window.pop_front();
        window.push_back(number);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

However, this strikes me as a little unwieldy. Is there a way to solve this without cloning or duplicating the iterator? In other words: is there a way to split an iterator into two segments that can be used independently?

Comment: The duplicate applied to your question: `pub fn analysis<I>(mut numbers: I, w: usize)` / `numbers.by_ref().take(w)`.

Comment: Even better, you can write it as `let window: VecDeque<_> = numbers.by_ref().take(w).collect();`

Comment: @Shepmaster, a rust noob here. Any chance you know where in the docs I can find an explanation of why the bound `I: Iterator<Item = u64>` works here, even though numbers.tee() is called and `tee()` is not part of the Iterator trait?  I expected the bound to be `I: Itertools<Item = u64>` in order to use the `tee()` method.  That works, but it is not required.   Is that just how "supertraits" work?  (I don't expect an answer here, but a link to docs or related questions would be great.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser [`Itertools` is implemented for any type that is an `Iterator`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#implementors). See also [How can I add new methods to Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30540766/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks.  Looks like I have some experimenting to do.

Comment: @Shepmaster I tried that before posting, but apparently overlooked the `mut` and misread the error I got. Now it works -.- Thank you for your help.