# Make stream combination exhaust once one of its underlying streams are exhausted

Tags: stream, rust, future

If I want to combine multiple same-typed streams into one, I would use [`Stream::select`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.select):

```
let combined = first_stream.select(second_stream)
```

However, once one of the streams is exhausted, the other can still produce results for the combined stream. What can I use to exhaust the combined stream once either of the underlying streams is exhausted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own stream combinator:

```
use futures::{Async, Poll, Stream}; // 0.1.25

struct WhileBoth<S1, S2>(S1, S2)
where
    S1: Stream,
    S2: Stream<Item = S1::Item, Error = S1::Error>;

impl<S1, S2> Stream for WhileBoth<S1, S2>
where
    S1: Stream,
    S2: Stream<Item = S1::Item, Error = S1::Error>,
{
    type Item = S1::Item;
    type Error = S1::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        match self.0.poll() {
            // Return errors or ready values (including the `None`
            // that indicates the stream is empty) immediately.
            r @ Err(_) | r @ Ok(Async::Ready(_)) => r,
            // If the first stream is not ready, try the second one.
            Ok(Async::NotReady) => self.1.poll(),
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How can I add new methods to Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30540766/155423)

Comment: So there is no such built-in possibility? Ok, thanks!