# How can I define a function that returns true if every value in an iterator is true?

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to define a function `every` which takes in an iterator and while it's not `None`, makes sure that all values are `true`.

Example applications:

```
every([true, true, true].into_iter()) == true
```

```
every([true, false, true].into_iter()) == false
```

I've had trouble getting it to work just with a `Vec`, let alone an `Iterator`. I've tried the following and a few variations but haven't gotten anywhere.

```
use std::ops;

fn every<T>(v: Vec<T>) -> bool
where
    T: ops::Not,
{
    for item in v {
        match !item {
            T::No => return false,
        }
    }
    true
}
```

This code gets the error:

```
error[E0599]: no associated item named `No` found for type `T` in the current scope
 --> src/lib.rs:9:13
  |
9 |             T::No => return false,
  |             ^^^^^ associated item not found in `T`
```

Comment: You could use [`Iterator::all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all)

Comment: [exemple](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee49af6daf752d20f3804586ce83b98e), be aware that here you are not using an iterator, see [all()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more generic example based on [Stargateur's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968385/defining-an-every-function-in-rust#comment94774659_53968385)

```
fn every<T, I>(v: I) -> bool
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: std::ops::Not<Output = bool>,
{
    v.into_iter().all(|x| !!x)
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0c2875162be8526d6fbcb973754ce73))

`v` can be anything that implements `IntoIterator`, e.g. a `Vec`, but also something like `map`, or `filter`, which makes this solution very generic.

Comment: Would it be possible to cast `x` to a bool instead of using `!!`. I tried `x as bool` and `bool::from(x)` but they both did not work.

Comment: I took the compilers suggestion and used the trait `bool: std::convert::From<T> instead of std::ops::Not<Output = bool>`. This allowed me to use `x.into()` instead of double negation. Both seem to work for my particular project, I wouldn't know which is the superior method in this case, or if they are equivalent.

Comment: @z.f.s `!!x` is an idiom from C where it is useful for turning a truthy integer into a real `true` or `false` (which are just 1 and 0 if you look closely). Rust doesn't have "truthiness" (`!` on integers does a bitwise NOT), so I wouldn't use it here. In fact I would not make T generic at all if you only intend to use `every` on `bool`-containing iterators, but I might choose `T: Borrow<bool>` to abstract over references if desired.

Comment: Related: [How can I add new methods to Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30540766/155423)

Comment: It's not super idiomatic to define two generic types [when one will do](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ea37bc8f960cf1e83d8e92b676e516a)