# How to create a trait that return a flatmap

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a trait that extends iterator from strings and return a flat map, here is what I got so far

```
trait WordsExt<'a, F>: Iterator<Item = &'a str>
where
    Self: Sized,
    F: FnMut(&'a str) -> Split<'a, &'a str>,
{
    fn words(self) -> FlatMap<Self, Split<'a, &'a str>, F> {
        self.flat_map(|x: &'a str| x.split(" "))
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on closure type.

I tried this too

```
struct Words<'a, I>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
{
    inner: I,
}

trait WordsExt<'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a str>
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    fn words(
        self,
    ) -> Words<'a, FlatMap<Self, Split<'a, &'a str>, Fn(Self::Item) -> Split<'a, &'a str>>>
    {
        Words {
            inner: self.flat_map(|x: &'a str| x.split(" ")),
        }
    }
}
```

I just came across this problem every time. I need to return a trait. When I'm in a function I can use `impl Trait` syntax. But when expressing a trait I can't express this. From what I could grasp, the closer I can get is to use generics, so that the method is monomorphized at call. But then I need to enable user to select the concrete type. In this case the closure is implementation detail, it should not leak to user.

I came across this answer [How can I add new methods to Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540766/how-can-i-add-new-methods-to-iterator)

In this case the OP use case has an inner state. In my case I just want to create an alias `i.words() -> i.flat_map(|x| x.split(" "))`

I know about coherence, so that I may need to create a wrapper over Iterator because Iterator is not under my crate. This was the second attempt.

I could implement a function by the way it was straightforward

```
fn words<'a>(i: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> {
    i.flat_map(|x| x.split(" "))
}
```

But I can't express the same with trait syntax because there is no `impl Trait` syntax in traits. So ... I have two options, dynamic dispatch and generics, none of them are ideal. Going even further. Since these struct is unsized I can't use static dispatch on it, so I'm stuck on dynamic dispatch on something that would be simply simple

*Invalid struct bellow*

```
struct Words<'a>(Iterator<Item = &'a str>);
```

Finally, I expected that given a function `F(X)` I would be able to always refactor it to write a `X.F()`, but this seems not to be true because while I'm able to write `fn f(x) -> impl Y` I'm not able to express `trait X { fn (self) -> impl Y }`, at last not recurring to generics or dynamic dispatch.

I was trying to write iterator combinators in a kind of fluent syntax: `iterator.comb1().comb2().comb3()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your code to compile by changing it as follows:

```rust
trait WordsExt<'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a str>
where
  Self: Sized,
{
  fn words(self) -> FlatMap<Self, Split<'a, &'a str>, fn(&'a str) -> Split<'a, &'a str>> {
    self.flat_map(|x: &'a str| x.split(" "))
  }
}
```

The trick is to replace the function trait object by the actual function type.

Comment: What is the difference of Fn and fn?

Comment: By the way thank you so much. Each time I came across problems like this is like solving a math puzzle

Comment: `Fn` is a trait while `fn` is a type. Since you know which function you want to apply to your elements, you don't need any generic `Fn`.

Comment: `fn(&'a str) -> Split<'a, &'a str>` is a function *pointer* type, which means using it incurs a (small) performance penalty over using the function type itself (which is how `impl Trait` works, but not currently possible in a trait).